# Send response to all clients with FLASK

Tags: python, flask, response

I am developing an application with flask, which has a page with a map drawn on it, it is generated by a JSON, when a change is made on the map by the user it sends the change to the server and this makes a response to the user that made the request.

What i want is that when making the response it is made to all the users that are connected to the page so that the information is refreshed, and not only for the one who made the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to implement some registration mechanizm for clients, so when an update occur, you iterate over clients in the registration list and send them the new data

to implement the actual push, you can do it with **web-sockets** (best for high throughput and small messages) or you can use [**server-send-event**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) for that (much simpler implementation mainly because it's riding on the http protocol)

there are other approaches using more advanced techniques, but, those 2 are the simplest and basic ones

Comment: I think that the web sockets are the thing i was looking for despite it seems a bit complex to implement in my actual project, i have been reading about flask-socketIO, which seems to be very useful, i will try implement it on the project
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is notification in `push`

im guessing one of the possible options for you is to make you javascript code \ or html to send a request every few minutes to check for new json

it can be simple done with ajax and interval

Comment: I have implemented a timer with javascript to send a request every few time, it does the work for now
Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Zabi No problem :), mark the answer as currect if this is what you find out as the answer for your question